# Parse database initialization- app crashes when navigating back to MainActivity

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

When my project starts up it's fine. MainActivity starts and then it navigates to another page but when I navigate back to MainActivity I sometimes get this error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QkvY.jpg
I'm positive this is from calling `Parse.enableLocalDatastore` before `Parse.initialize` but here is my code for mainActivity

```
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Parse.initialize(this, "MY_INFO", "MY_INFO_AGAIN");

    // check if a user is not cached
    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser == null)
    {
        // prompt user to LoginOrSignUp screen
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginOrSignUpActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }`
```

local data store is called before initialize but it still crashes. I don't get it. I can communicate with my data base just fine and everything but as soon as I navigate back to main it crashes

Comment: let me know if your problem solved or not!

Comment: So if I'm following you correctly, just put it in a new class, put it in my manifest then everything should be fixed? Do I need to still call it when my app starts or is it automatically initialized when it starts

Comment: no you don't need to call in your MainActivity.. not anywhere.. just put in this class that's it..n atleast try first.. you got to try to know if it fixes or not

Comment: crashes on start up http://imgur.com/VFuNkW6

Comment: post the MANIFEST FILE you changed.. and the class you created... and can you please change the title of your question as "Parse database initialization- app crashes when navigating back to MainActivity" .. something like that??

Comment: class file http://imgur.com/pJAzPaZ manifest http://imgur.com/CxhtHC0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should initialize your Parse SDK in separate class as follows

```
public class SampleApplication extends Application {
   public void onCreate(){
       super.onCreate();
       Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext());
       Parse.initialize(this, "PARSE_APP_KEY", "PARSE_CLIENT_KEY");
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
   }
}
```

**IMPORTANT!!!** you need to put this class info in your AndroidManifest.xml file.
hope it helps!

Comment: your welcome.. can you please change the title of your question as.. "Parse database initialization- app crashes when navigating back to MainActivity" like this please?